# If children has class, add class to specific parent id (pure Javasript), no jQuery

Tags: javascript

enter code here

```js
const child = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion span.xh_find");
const parents = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="acc-"]');

if (document.querySelector(".accordion span").classList.contains("xh_find")) {
  
parents.forEach(item => item.classList.add('xh_find_parent'));
// Hm, should not add class to all parents, only if children has class="xh_find"! HowTo?
}
```

```css
.xh_find_parent {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">

  <div id="acc-1">
    <p>
      Text with <span class="xh_find">class</span>.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="acc-2">
    <p>
      Text without class.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="acc-3">
    <p>
      Text with <span class="xh_find">class</span>.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="acc-4">
    <p>
      Text with <span class="xh_find">class</span>.
    </p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="acc-5">
    <p>
      Text without class.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

How is it possible?
The parent id should get the class "xh_find_parent" only if the child element has the class "xh_find". In my code example all are extended with this class.

Comment: Why do you always only test the first `<span>` (`.querySelector(".accordion span")`)?

Comment: `parents.forEach(item => item.classList.add('xh_find_parent'));` - As the name of the method `.forEach()` suggests, every element in the collection `parents` will be processed. Why do you think that only one of them (and how should the script know which one) will be processed?

Comment: Have a look at [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and you will find a much easier way to solve this requirement.

Comment: Thank you Andreas for your quick reply. Since I understand very little about javascript, I could not find a solution on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Once you selected `parents`:

- loop them with `forEach()`
- for each item of parents, check (with `querySelector()`) if there is some child with the required class `xh_find`
- if exist at least one child with that class, add `xh_find_parent` class to the item

```js
// 
const parents = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="acc-"]');

parents.forEach(item => {
  const childHasClass = item.querySelector('.xh_find'); // <- yield 'null' if no children with that class

  if (childHasClass) {
    item.classList.add('xh_find_parent');
  }
})
```

```css
.xh_find_parent {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">

  <div id="acc-1">
    <p>
      Text with <span class="xh_find">class</span>.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="acc-2">
    <p>
      Text without class.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="acc-3">
    <p>
      Text with <span class="xh_find">class</span>.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="acc-4">
    <p>
      Text with <span class="xh_find">class</span>.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="acc-5">
    <p>
      Text without class.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello cheesyMan. That works! Great, thank you very much. I'm thrilled about such quick help and answers. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as below, explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// we only really need to know two things for this solution,
// although we could also use a variable for the '.accordion';
// the 'needle' is the class-name we're searching for:
const needle = 'xh_find',
// the 'classToAdd' is the class we wish to add to the ancestor
// of the 'xh_find' elements:
      classToAdd = 'xh_find_parent';

// here we use a template-literal to concatenate the 'needle'
// variable into the selector for document.querySelectorAll();
// this is resolved to '.accordion .xh_find'; we then use
// NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the NodeList:
document.querySelectorAll(`.accordion .${needle}`).forEach(
  // here we use an Arrow function expression, to pass in
  // a reference to the current element-node of the
  // NodeList over which we're iterating,to the body of the
  // function.
  // In the function-body, we retrieve the first of the
  // element's ancestor elements that has an id attribute:
  (el) => el.closest('[id]')
            // and then we use the Element.classList API:
            .classList
            // to add the 'classToAdd' value to the
            // classes of the recovered ancestor:
            .add(classToAdd)
);
```

```css
/* The CSS is irrelevant to the demo; however:
   this is a simple reset, to have all elmenents
   and pseudo-elements use the same layout, margin,
   padding and font: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: normal 400 1rem / 1.5 sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* using grid layout as that maintains the desired
   layout; but allows the use of 'gap' to place a
   regular space between adjacent elements without
   having to work with margins: */
.accordion {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5em;
  /* places a margin on the block axis of the content,
     the top and bottom in left-to-right/top-to-bottom
     languages: */
  margin-block: 1em;
  /* defines the margin on the inline-axis of the content,
     the left and right in left-to-right (and right-to-left)
     languages: */
  margin-inline: auto;
  /* defines the width as 70 viewport-widths (70% of the
     width of the viewport), but sets a minimum width of
     20em and a maximum width of 600px: */
  width: clamp(20em, 70vw, 600px);
}

.xh_find_parent {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">

  <div id="acc-1">
    <p>
      Text with <span class="xh_find">class</span>.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="acc-2">
    <p>
      Text without class.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="acc-3">
    <p>
      Text with <span class="xh_find">class</span>.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="acc-4">
    <p>
      Text with <span class="xh_find">class</span>.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="acc-5">
    <p>
      Text without class.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tph065ax/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`clamp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
  - [`margin-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block).
  - [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
  - [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Hello David. Thanks for your quick help! Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. The Browser Console reports:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.accordion .${needle}' is not a valid selector.

Comment: This work:

`const needle = '.lck_accordion [id^="acc-"] .xh_find';
 classToAdd = 'xh_find_parent';
document.querySelectorAll(needle).forEach(
 (el) => el.closest('[id]')
 .classList
 .add(classToAdd)
);`

Comment: @ David: So, tested again. It works after all! My mistake, I must apologize to you. I am sorry.

Comment: @Ick: no problem at all :)